# Newbie looking to learn nested JSON

Tags: arrays, json, csv, nested

I just started learning JSON and how to convert back and forth between different file types.

If I'm trying to convert a CSV file to JSON

Say if I have a CSV file of people

```
(First name, Last name, age)
David Chin 40
David Lin 40
David Ping 30
Sandra Lee 25
Sandra Long 45
```

I can convert that to JSON without any formatting.

How would I go about trying to convert the CSV to a nested JSON?

Hopefully output would look like

```
{"David":{
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"Chin": "40"
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; "Lin": "40"
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; "Ping": "30"
},
"Sandra":{
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    "Lee": "25"
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    "Long": "45"}

}
```

Is there any particular code where I can freely format the conversion?

Any help toward the right direction is appreciated or pointers on how to format JSON would also work. I just don't know where I would manipulate to get that format in the output.

Comment: JSON itself is just a text document, it does not have a concept of keys. You can format it however you like, which depends on your use case, data model, and business logic. Are you asking how to create the JSON from the CSV?

Comment: yeah. creating a json from the csv.

Comment: Have you made any attempt? What language are trying to do this in? There are a number of approaches you can take. There are even automated CSV to JSON parsers on the web.

Comment: I'm trying to do it in python. I did see the automated CSV to JSON parsers on the web but it doesn't do the desired output above.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: I also know there are a few examples of converting csv to JSON on stackoverflow but I can't figure out where to change to code to get the format I'm looking for. It just comes out as a continuous blob.

Comment: `#! usr/bin/env python

import codecs, json, nltk, sys
import csv


csvfile = open('csv.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('table5.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("Name","Last Name","Age")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )
jsonfile.write(out)`

Comment: Upvote for actually correctly referring to JSON. There has been too many questions lately thinking a JavaScript object and JSON are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

If the file `filter.jq` contains

```
[
  split("\n")                                # split string into lines
| [.[0]    | split(",")[]] as $headers       # split header
| (.[1:][] | split(","))                     # split data
| select(length>0)                           # eliminate blanks
| [   [ $headers, . ]                        # 
    | transpose[]                            # assemble objects
    | {key:.[0], value:.[1]}                 # from keys and values
  ] | from_entries                           #
]
| reduce group_by(.First)[][] as $r (        # construct final result
    {}
  ; .[$r.First] = (.[$r.First]//{}) * {($r.Last):$r.Age}
  )
```

and `data` contains

```
First,Last,Age
David,Chin,40
David,Lin,40
David,Ping,30
Sandra,Lee,25
Sandra,Long,45
```

then the command

```
jq -M -R -s -r -f filter.jq data
```

will produce the output

```
{
  "David": {
    "Chin": "40",
    "Lin": "40",
    "Ping": "30"
  },
  "Sandra": {
    "Lee": "25",
    "Long": "45"
  }
}
```